# Powershell parametersets and pipline input

Tags: powershell

**Short Background:**

The original function creates printers. Some of them have a build in printserver and can do stuff like scanning and / or print on special paper. Others are connected to a box and print via lpd / lpr. This printers can print only.

**Parameter description:**

PrinterName and InvetoryID are common to both
LprAddress and LprQueue indicates a printer that cannot use Scan2Folder, CreateBfbPrinters and PsAddress.

I'm using parametersets and because there is no mandatory parameter that is exclusive for the "Printserver"-set I made this the default parameterset.

**Error:**

Everything works as expected but input from pipline (by property name) seems to end in the parameterset "LPR" no matter what properties are provided.

```
function Test-ParamsetPipeline {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Printserver")]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True)]
        [String]$PrinterName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True)]
        [String]$InventoryID,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True,ParameterSetName="LPR")]
        [String]$LprAddress,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True,ParameterSetName="LPR")]
        [string]$LprQueue,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True)]
        [Switch]$CreateBfbPrinters,
        [parameter(ParameterSetName="Printserver")]
        [Switch]$Scan2Folder,
        [parameter(ParameterSetName="Printserver")]
        [System.Security.SecureString]$PasswordDeviceaccount,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True,ParameterSetName="Printserver")]
        [String]$PsAddress
    )

    PROCESS {
        Write-Output $psCmdlet.ParameterSetName
    }
}

#Test1
Test-ParamsetPipeline -PrinterName "Printer1" -InventoryID "12345"
#No error - works as expected

#Test2
Test-ParamsetPipeline -PrinterName "Printer1" -InventoryID "12345" -LprAddress "1.1.1.1" -LprQueue "lp1"
#No error - works as expected

#Test3
Test-ParamsetPipeline -PrinterName "Printer1" -InventoryID "12345" -LprAddress "1.1.1.1" -LprQueue "lp1" -Scan2Folder
#Error - works as expected (Scan2Folder is not allowed on LPR-Printers)

#Test4
$Obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    PrinterName = "Printer1"
    InventoryID = "12345"
}
$Obj | Test-ParamsetPipeline
#Error:
# Test-ParamsetPipeline : Der Parametersatz kann mit den angegebenen benannten Parametern nicht aufgelöst werden.
# Bei \\elbekliniken.de\system\EkScripts\Dev\Test.ps1:36 Zeichen:22
#+ Test-ParamsetPipeline <<<<  -PrinterName "Printer1" -InventoryID "12345" -LprAddress "1.1.1.1" -LprQueue "lp1" -Scan2Folder
#    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-ParamsetPipeline], ParameterBindingException
#    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Test-ParamsetPipeline
#
# Translation: Cannot resolve Parameterset with the given parameters.

#Test5
$Obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    PrinterName = "Printer1"
    InventoryID = "12345"
    PsAddress = "2.2.2.2"
}
$Obj | Test-ParamsetPipeline
# Same error as above

#Test6
$Obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    PrinterName = "Printer1"
    InventoryID = "12345"
    LprAddress = "1.1.1.1"
    LprQueue = "lp1"
}
$Obj | Test-ParamsetPipeline
#No error - works as expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have liked to write this as a comment, but I can't create comments this long and formatted nicely. However, I must say that I do not get the same behavior as you mention.

When I run it in PowerShell version 4 (on a Win8.1 machine) it works completely as expected and all tests (except number 3, which is expected to fail) run nicely.

When I run it in PowerShell version 2 (on a Win8.1 machine with PS4 installed) I do get errors on test 4 and 5 as well, but I get other errors than you mention. The error I receive on test 4 and 5 is:

```
Test-ParamsetPipeline : The input object cannot be bound because it did not contain the information required to bind all mandatory parameters:  LprAddress LprQueue
At <mypath>\paramsettest.ps1:60 char:29
+ $Obj | Test-ParamsetPipeline <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{PsAddress=2.2...rName=Printer1}:PSObject) [Test-ParamsetPipeline], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectMissingMandatory,Test-ParamsetPipeline
```

My FullyQualifiedErrorId is InputObjectMissingMandatory while you mention getting AmbiguousParameterSet. And, again, on PowerShell version 4 it works perfectly fine on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for testing this. It's pretty clear now that this is a Bug in older Versions.

Comment: I think the differences within the error messages are caused by multiple translations. Your english version (probably the original form MS development) was translatet to german an than I've translated it back to english.

Comment: Yes, the error message difference is partly because of translations, but not entirely. The FullyQualifiedErrorId in PowerShell is supposed to be identical independent of translations, so the fact that those differ means that we actually get different errors. The difference is also pretty clear, actually; InputObjectMissingMandatory seem to indicate that it has successfully selected a parameter set but it fails to provide values for all mandatory parameters of the parameter set, while AmbigiousParameterSet seem to indicate that it can't select parameter set successfully.